# Почему периодически отваливается MySql?

Tags: php, mysql, битрикс24

На корпоративном портале иногда кратковременно отваливается MySql.

Первое, что пришло в голову - перегрузка сервера, однако загрузка его - 30%.

Уточнил у админов, говорят, раз в 2 часа БД делает какие-то срезы. Возможно, это является причиной?

Подскажите, как это проверить? Если это важно - Битрикс24.

Comment: что вы подразумеваете под "отваеливается", что в логах?

Comment: в /var/log/mysql/error.log записей очень много, как отыскать нужную? прислали только скрин http://piccy.info/view3/12126791/f6516485ebf0135eba23fb548e2ab73b/

Comment: включайте вывод ошибок. включайте логирование и смотрите. приложенный скрин не сообщает ничего. как падает mysql тоже неизвестно, потому что проблема решается из условий его возникновения.